# Fill an array from keyboard in Java

Tags: arrays, arraylist, numbers, fill

Good morning,
I'm new in programming.
I'm trying to write a program which reads some numbers from the keyboard and will sum them. I reached to write a program which sum the numbers, my problem is that i don't know how to configure the Scanner to fill an array/ArrayList. 
How could i do?
This is my code.

```
class array {
public static void main(String[] args) {
   int start = 0;
   int [] interi = {2,3,6,10,24,45};

   for (int i:interi)
      start+=i;         //++  

   System.out.println(start);
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't know how to configure the Scanner to fill an array/ArrayList. How could i do?

To populate an ArrayList as the user gets prompted:

```
//example, prompt user 3 times
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
    list.add(scn.nextInt());
```

If using array:

```
array[i] = scn.nextInt();
```

However, take note that array has fixed size. So you don't want to prompt more than the given array size.

If user is to be prompted unknown number of times, use a while loop with array list.